# Detect when a user switches windows

Tags: windows, hook

I'm curious to know if this is possible, I want to know when a window loses focus.

I know in linux it can all be seen with xev (perhaps multiple sessions monitoring all the windows), but I need a solution in Windows.

A VM running windows in seamless mode does not help - since all internal windows are considered the 'virtualbox window', xev does not pick up internal activity.

Is there a hook to do this? Are there any other ways? I can't count on the user using alt-tab, some may click to change windows.

Comment: I'm no expert, but looking at [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#types) it sounds like a `WH_CBT` hook would do the trick.

Comment: Brydon, What are you *really trying to do*?  There's probably a better way than doing a hook (which can lead to system instability).